# Personalise web part based on various users

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts, personalization

I all,

I have a requirement where I have to write a web part that configurable to all users. Each user can able to modify the web part and personalise it based on there preference. So when next time he gets login he will see configutation settings set by him...!

Any help will be appriciable !!!

Thanks in Advance!
Sachin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is how to design such a webpart, that each user can personalize for him-/herself?

All you need is to save the user preferences either to a dedicated Sharepoint List linking the user to his/her preferences with all your settings included or you save the preferences to a database/table again linking the user to his/her preferences.

You could also store the user's preferences in the profile like explained in this article: [How To: Create custom SharePoint 2010 User Profile properties programatically](http://www.sharemuch.com/2010/03/30/how-to-create-custom-sharepoint-2010-user-profile-properties-programatically/).

It really depends on you where you want to save it. Upon calling the webpart all you need to do is find out the user currently accessing the webpart and connect to his settings.

Comment: Thanks moontear..! really appriciate your help. :)